# Unchecking ListViewItems recursively

Tags: c#, listview, user-interface, recursion, checkbox

I have a ListView with cascading checkboxes inside of it. What I would like to do is be able to uncheck all child boxes if the parent box is unchecked (and similarly I'd like to check all child boxes if the parent is checked). Currently, if I check or uncheck a box, the parent node and child nodes are greyed out, but the check mark is still visible on the child boxes.

I presume I'd have to do this recursively. I've given the following code a try and I think it should work, but it breaks at runtime due to casting issues.

```
private void listViewChildNodeModifier(ListViewItem item)
  {
     if (item.SubItems.Equals(null)) return;
     else
     {
        foreach (ListViewItem childItem in item.SubItems)
        {
           listViewChildNodeModifier(childItem);
           if(childItem.Tag is TestingNode)
              ((TestingNode)childItem.Tag).Enabled = item.Checked;
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you not do this

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in this.ListView.Items)
{            
    for (int i = 0; i < item.SubItems.Count; i++)
    {
        item.SubItems[i].Checked = false; 
        //will something like this work for you let me know
    }
}
```

another alternative which should work as well would be the following

```
foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem childItem in item.SubItems)
 {
   if(item.Checked)
   {
     item.Checked = false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: No, I see no such property `SelectedItems` in the API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The issue is that `item.SubItems()` returns a collection of `ListViewSubItem`s rather than a `ListViewItem`. Unfortunately, there is no property which enables me to check or uncheck a `ListViewSubItem` as far as I'm aware (then again, I just learned C# last week, so there's a very good chance I'm wrong haha)

Comment: let me know if that helps you need the inner loop to access the SubItems by their Index position which in this case will be `i`

Comment: not sure if you want to check existing CheckedState or are if I am to assume that you want to set them to false regardless.. change the code to match your condition :) best of luck

Comment: Still looking at this, might give it a better look tomorrow when I come back into the office. But For the second one, how's that going to do anything other than disable the currently checked box?

Comment: based on what you are wanting if I understand you correctly that code should actually work.. please clarify my assumptions

Comment: What I'm saying is that the loop iterates over `item.SubItems`; that is, it assigns a SubItem to childItem, but you're assigning `false` to `item.Checked` rather than `childItem.Checked`. So it's just gonna keep modifying item.Checked for every SubItem and do nothing with the SubItem itself. Now the problem lies in the fact that SubItem does not have a Checked property as far as I can tell.

Comment: For instance, here is the documentation for ListViewSubItem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx